# DI, IoC Bindings with ninject (Binding Interface to IEnumerable<T> method)

Tags: c#, binding, ninject

I have an interface:

```
public interface IProductRepository {
    IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }
}
```

A method:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> getProducts() { }
```

My controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List() {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

I am trying to bind them together in AddBindings() {

```
productDAL db = new productDAL();
IEnumerable<Product> help = db.getProducts();
kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To< >;
```

I was trying to use the method instead of something like this:

```
Mock<IProductRepostiory> mock = new Mock<IProductRespository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> {
new Product { Name= ... }

kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
```

but use something like the ToMethod or whatever. The getProducts() returns a IEnumerable from the database, which then I want ninject to inject to the ProductsController, so I can so a List to the View. I know that the class Product doesn't inherit IProductDepository nor does the productDAL, that is on purpose.

this is in my DependencyResolver class.

Can someone please help with the binding here, I am missing a cast something, thank you.

---

I figured it out, this is what I did to fix it:

I have an interface:

```
public interface IProductRepository {
    IEnumerable<CountyDataset> Products { get; }
}
```

I have a MVC controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List() {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

I have a DAL:

```
public class productDAL: databaseDAL {
    public productDAL() {

    }
    public IEnumerable<CountyDataset> Products {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

This is what I was missing...

Now I have a Product Repository (and friends haha):

```
public class lcProducts : IProductRepository {
    private productDAL context = new productDAL();

    public IEnumerable<CountyDataset> Products {
        get { return context.Products; }
    }
}
```

And here is my corrected DI container:

```
private void AddBindings() {
        ...
        kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<lcProducts>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't -- the types don't match. You have to bind to an instance of `IProductRepository`. Looks like your `db` object implements the interface, so give this a try:

```
kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<productDAL>();
.
.
.
var db = kernel.Get<IProductRepository>();
IEnumerable<Product> help = db.getProducts();
```

Keep in mind, this doesn't really buy you very much though. You should have the `IProductRepository` as a constructor dependency on other classes for DI to really work its magic. Here's the class you provided being used accordingly.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List() {
        return View(repository.Products);
    }
}
```

Where your dependency resolver now looks like this:

```
kernel.Bind<SomeConsumerOfProductRepository>().ToSelf();
kernel.Bind<Controller>().To<ProductController>();
.
.
.
var consumer = kernel.Get<Controller>();
//Use consumer or do whatever you have to do....
```

This will allow Ninject to automatically detect that `ProductController` has a dependency on `IProductRepository`, which you've bound to an implementation, and resolve it for you. In addition to that, you can easily change `ProductController` for a new implementation of `Controller` seamlessly if the need should arise.

Comment: The consumer is going to be my ProductController
    
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository) {
            this.repository = productRepository;
        }
        
        public ViewResult List() {
            return View(repository.Products);
        }
    }

Comment: if I do this:

kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<productDAL>();

I get this

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0311 The type 'DataLibrary.Dal.productDAL' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'IBindingToSyntax<IProductRepository>.To<TImplementation>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DataLibrary.Dal.productDAL' to 'DataLibrary.Interfaces.IProductRepository'. ClerkHelper c:\users\hanka\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ClerkHelper\ClerkHelper\Slab\NinjectDependencyResolv

Comment: That's because your `productDAL` class doesn't implement the `IProductRepository` interface.

Comment: I know that I was trying to do something like this: 

Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRespository>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product> { new Product { Name=... } 

kernel.Bind<IProductRespsitory>().ToConstant(mock.Object);

Comment: That will work. It's tough to answer because I feel like I'm missing a ton of context here.

Comment: I want to use my method instead so I can get my products from a method that gets the products from a db

Comment: thanks, I added more to my OP, thank you for your reponse

Comment: I understand now. You can't (to my knowledge, I could be wrong) bind a method of an interface to a method on an implementation. The `ToMethod` function is for binding an interface to an implementation that is generated *from* a method. Not to bind an implementation's method to an interface's method.

Comment: I figured it out and updated my OP, thanks again. scratching my head for nothing but I hope DI is worth it.

Comment: It is worth it.